# Развертывание репозитория GIT

Tags: git

На сервере (Windows) в локальной сети создан bare-репозиторий, содержит 2 ветки: master и test.
Для развертывания настроен хук post-receive:

```bsh
...
stdgit="$(git --work-tree=${full_work_dir} --git-dir=${git_dir} checkout --force ${copy_branch} 2>&1)";
...
```

- full_work_dir - шара на другом сервере.
- copy_branch - ветка.

На машине разработчика также есть репозиторий. Работа выглядит примерно так: переключаемся на ветку test, вносим изменения в файлы, делаем commit&push, все уходит на сервер, хук отрабатывает и файлы размещаются на full_work_dir. Если после этого переключиться на ветку master и тоже внести изменения, например сделать merge ветки test или просто внести изменения в файлы и выполнить commit&push, все уходит на сервер, хук отрабатывает и файлы размещаются на full_work_dir. Но в этом случае обновляются (перезаписываются) все файлы в full_work_dir и меняется дата изменения файлов. Если все время находиться в одной ветке и делать commit&push, то все работает нормально, в full_work_dir обновляется только измененный файл, стоит только переключиться на другую ветку и выполнить commit&push, то опять все перезаписывается.

**Вопрос**: как правильно настроить процесс, чтобы не происходило полного обновления рабочего каталога?

Comment: у Вас хук помоему копирует всю ветку, проблема в нём

Comment: *Если все время находиться в одной ветке и делать commit&push, то все работает нормально* - совершенно верно, всё работает нормально (вероятно, с вашей точки зрения - ненормально): обновляются timestamp-ы у всех файлов. ровно так, [как и задумано](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F). если вы хотите обновлять только избранные файлы - их вам и надо указать явно: `$ git checkout ... -- файл1 файл2 ...`

Comment: Вы объясните, какую проблему решает этот вычурный способ копирования репозитория?